# for loop going over the index len?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

I have to iterate over a len of my data frame dimension, I get an error which says: `ValueError: **153353** is not in range`.
As you see I the range of stop at 153352-1. Even if I set it to 153351 I got the shame error. Despite the error my `namefiledict` is filled. The error come at the last row(which is filled)

```
#
namefile = []
for docs in list(df[0][0][0]):
    for allwav in docs:
        for onewavfile in allwav:
            namefile.append(onewavfile)


namefiledict = {}
for i in range(0, 153351,1):
    for name in namefile:
        namefiledict[name] = list(df[i][0])
```

I've also tried `for idx, name in enumerate(df):` but this also lead to same error.

[UPDATE]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~/anaconda3/envs/rpython/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
        375             try:
    --> 376                 return self._range.index(new_key)
        377             except ValueError:

```
ValueError: 153353 is not in range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-30d2f7a02ddf> in <module>
      4 for i in range(0, 153351,1):
      5     for name in namefile:
----> 6         namefiledict[name] = list(df[i][0])
      7         i+=1

~/anaconda3/envs/rpython/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2993             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2994                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2995             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2996             if is_integer(indexer):
   2997                 indexer = [indexer]

~/anaconda3/envs/rpython/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    376                 return self._range.index(new_key)
    377             except ValueError:
--> 378                 raise KeyError(key)
    379         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
    380 

KeyError: 153353
```

Comment: The easiest way to loop over a dataframes, use `df.itertuples()`, although generally there is a better way. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'd like to iterate over this df and get the array into one of it's column then add it to dict. But why it says that error?

Comment: Post the full error message including the stack trace. You should always do that.

Comment: You are getting a keyerror because that index isn't in the dataframe. Why are you incrementing `i`? See the answer below

Comment: As juanpa.arrivillaga said, explicit loops should be a last resort. Can you share more of your code and data, as well as explain what your program is meant to do?

Comment: I updated it. I need to extract mat file to dataframe. I'm only interested to two cols I selected. When I transform to df, the features are stacked in one row with 153353 column. I should have 153353 rows with two columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line of your code increases `i` by one. That is what puts the loop over as `i` is already being incremented by the `for-loop` logic. You need to delete this line.

When using that form of the for statement you let python handle the incrementing.

Comment: I notice whne i delete it It take me too long time, like the look never end. That's why I added it.  may be the complexity. `namefile` is a list and has 153353 elements.

Comment: @abdoulsn It's probably taking forever because it's not idiomatic Pandas. Have you read the docs?

Comment: What do you mean in idiomatic Pandas?

Comment: It's working I deleted that one. But it take to long time.